# Is it possible to have an convergent and stationary ARMA process with AR coefficients greater than 1?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive

**tl; dr;** I am reading a book on time series. I've covered the theory and I am doing some practice by simulating ARMA processes and then trying to fit a model without having looked at the parameters. I hit a case in which the true model is ARMA(1,3) but I deduce it is ARMA(2,2). What surprised me is that the fitted model has an AR.1 coefficient of 1.07. Can a coefficient be larger than 1?

**Details below**

I encountered the following case. The true model is given below. It is an ARMA(1,3) with all roots outside the unit circle so the process is stationary and invertible.

```
p,1
q,3
arparams,[0.7932746359707682]
maparams,"[0.1642229347304477, 0.4399882819039773, 0.10301024656166147]"
stationary,True
invertible,True
arroots,[1.26059747]
maroots,[-4.4090944 +0.j          0.06889421-1.48223297j  0.06889421+1.48223297j]
```

I used AIC and BIC tables to determine the order. The min values for both are at (2,2)

AIC:

```
    0           1           2           3           4
0   4751.837712 3958.567134 3456.142801 3174.691149 3031.503007
1   3036.266701 3031.508284 2894.086963 2887.895710 2889.116463
2   3026.326356 3035.862545 2886.760873 2887.682070 2889.034554
3   2900.704681 2902.467845 2888.422767 2889.140943 2890.989289
4   2902.311698 2899.400977 2889.811332 2891.902368 2893.957176
```

BIC:

```
    0           1           2           3           4
0   4761.653223 3973.290400 3475.773822 3199.229925 3060.949539
1   3050.989967 3051.139305 2918.625739 2917.342242 2923.470750
2   3045.957377 3060.401322 2916.207404 2922.036357 2928.296596
3   2925.243457 2931.914376 2922.777054 2928.402985 2935.159087
4   2931.758230 2933.755264 2929.073374 2936.072165 2943.034728
```

So I fit an ARMA(2,2) model. Please note, the true process is ARMA(1,3).

```
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      0   No. Observations:                 1000
Model:                 ARIMA(2, 0, 2)   Log Likelihood               -1437.380
Date:                Thu, 01 Apr 2021   AIC                           2886.761
Time:                        12:24:49   BIC                           2916.207
Sample:                             0   HQIC                          2897.953
                               - 1000                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.0170      0.262     -0.065      0.948      -0.530       0.496
ar.L1          1.0702      0.078     13.660      0.000       0.917       1.224
ar.L2         -0.2312      0.074     -3.141      0.002      -0.376      -0.087
ma.L1         -0.1045      0.072     -1.449      0.147      -0.246       0.037
ma.L2          0.4129      0.033     12.629      0.000       0.349       0.477
sigma2         1.0353      0.045     22.902      0.000       0.947       1.124
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (Q):                       29.79   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 0.61
Prob(Q):                              0.88   Prob(JB):                         0.74
Heteroskedasticity (H):               1.06   Skew:                             0.00
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.57   Kurtosis:                         3.12
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

I then ran a Ljung-Box test on the residuals:

```
# Box-ljung test giving same output as Box.test in R
acorr, lbvalues, pvalues = acf(results.resid, nlags=30, qstat=True, fft=True)
print('X-squared: {:.4f}, df={}, p-value = {:.4f}'.format(lbvalues[-1], len(lbvalues), pvalues[-1]))
X-squared: 22.9239, df=30, p-value = 0.8184
```

p-value is 0.82 so we cannot reject H0: residuals are independently distributed.

However, the model shows that **ar.L1** is 1.07 (albeit with a confidence interval of (0.917, 1.224). How should I interpret this? I have 3 questions:

1. The roots of the AR(2) equation are outside the unit circle. If I remember correctly, we **also** want the AR coefficients to be less than 1 in modulus otherwise the series diverges. Is this correct or can the coefficient be over 1 and still lead to a stationary, convergent series?
2. If the coefficient must be less than 1, can I argue that the actual interval is (0.917, 1)?
3. Is the AR coefficient being over one a reason to suspect the model is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Coefficients can be greater than 1 as long as roots are outside the unit circle. For the case of AR(1) the single AR coefficient  less than one (in magnitude) is equivalent to root outside the unit circle. But not for AR(2), etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. We can write an AR(p) process as $f(B) X_t = Z_t$ where $f(B)$ is a p-order polynomial using the coefficients of the $X_{t-i}$ terms. Then $X_t = f^{-1}(B)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ would be an infinite series of increasing power of the coefficients and B so if any one of them is over 1 this will explode and the series will diverge. $B$ is the delay operator.

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning, but  the  stationarity region of an AR(2) (corresponding to all roots outside the unit circle) is bounded by $\phi_2 = -1$, $\phi_2 = 1 - \phi_1$, $\phi_2 = 1 + \phi_1$, which includes $|\phi_1| < 2$. Also, stationarity is all you need.